# Why blade file in laravel is not displaying?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, view, laravel-blade

I am new to laravel, I am trying display myaccount page using blade file in laravel. myaccount.blade.php is located in resources/views/myaccount.blade.php
[image: myaccount.blade.php]

Route in web.php as:

```
Route::get('/myaccount', 'HomeController@myaccount');
```

Then HomeController.php as:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use DB;
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
    public function registerUser(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
    }
    public function myaccount()
    {
        return view('myaccount');
    }
   
}
```

What my output shows:

[image: Output]

Comment: remove this function from HomeController...    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

Comment: Try to remove `.php` suffix of the url, and take a look at `storage/logs`.

Comment: try this url localhost/myaccount/public

Comment: as @rubys mentioned the .php suffix is extra. In laravel there is no need for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this function from **HomeController**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

and try url without **.php** extension

Comment: Thankyou it works.

Comment: welcome! actually public function __construct() contain the middleware and you are not login

Comment: Give Explanation in your answer about OP's mistake writing extension in url. EX. Why we cant use `.php` while accessing laravel pages. So that other users get benefited from it.